# Trigger to update value

Tags: before-trigger

As requested posting the code to update a certain field(is ready to be closed) value.

I am getting a DML operation cant be performed on trigger.new error.

Thanks

```
trigger triggers_for_sites on Site__c (after insert, after update) {
 if((trigger.isinsert||trigger.isupdate)&&trigger.isafter){
 Site_Trigger_Handler.updateSiteStatus(trigger.new);    
 }
}


public class Site_Trigger_Handler {
    public static void updateSiteStatus(List <Site__c> sites){
    List <Country_Application_Relationship__c> rel_list= new 
    List<Country_Application_Relationship__c>();
    List <Id> sites_ids = new List<id>();
    List <Site__c> site_open= new List<Site__c>();
    List <Site__c> site_close= new List<Site__c>();

    for(Site__c temp : sites){
        sites_ids.add(temp.id);
    }

    rel_list=[select id,Site__c,Site_Status__c from 
     Country_Application_Relationship__c where Site__c IN: sites_ids];

    for(Site__c temp_site : sites){
        for(Country_Application_Relationship__c temp_rel : rel_list){
            if(temp_site.Id==temp_rel.Site__c){
              if(temp_rel.Site_Status__c == 'Live'){
                      temp_site.Is_Ready_to_Close__c = 'No';
                      site_open.add(temp_site);
                break;
              }
               else if(temp_rel.Site_Status__c == 'Closed'){
                       temp_site.Is_Ready_to_Close__c = 'Yes';
                       site_close.add(temp_site);
                }

            }
        }
    }

      if(site_open!=null){
        update site_open;
      }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code here, what you have tried so far?

Comment: This description is quite incomplete. The implication (but there's no certainty) is that ObjectA is related to ObjectB. In addition to adding any existing code, you need to provide object model details. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/284177/edit) your question to add these details if you want help from the community.

Comment: Please don't paraphrase error messages. Doing so usually means that you've left out important information that would help get you an accurate answer. When asking for help with an error, including the full text and stack trace _verbatim_ is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks @Derek. New to this site. Will learn the best practices soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different errors that you can run into with code like this, but I think you included most of the error message that you're getting.

As the error tells you, DML cannot be performed on trigger context variables<sup>1</sup>. Part of this is Salesforce trying to help you avoid getting yourself into an infinite loop. Another part of this is an indication that *you're not using the right tool for the job*.

In general...

- `after` triggers are used when you want to update data for *SObjects other than the one the trigger is for*
- `before` triggers are used when you're altering data *on the same
  records that the trigger is running on*.

So, at the very least, you want to be running this code `before update`. That'll allow you to avoid needing to use DML to update the records (and you won't get into an infinite loop)

That leaves us with the question of what to do with the `after insert` bit. I'd argue that you should not perform this work on insert at all. Records being inserted are not given Ids until sometime after `before insert` finishes, but before `after insert` starts. That means that it's impossible for a record to be related to a new `Site__c` record until after the `after insert` trigger for `Site__c` starts running.

You could possibly have multiple triggers on `Site__c` (which is bad practice. We can't guarantee the order in which multiple triggers on a single object are executed), or be creating the related records in an `after` trigger. In both of those cases, however, you should have a direct mapping between `Site__c` records, and the related records you're creating. That would make running a query to get this information a waste of resources.

### Bonus

You have the following anti-pattern in your code:

```
for(ObjA__c rec1 :myRecs){
    for(ObjB__c rec2 :otherRecs){
        if(rec1.Field == rec2.Field){
            // do work
        }
    }
}
```

Not all nested loops are bad, but this is an example of a bad nested loop. You end up executing the `if` statement in the inner loop N * M times (N = size of `myRecs`, M = size of `otherRecs`), which becomes a large number even with modest values of N and M.

Instead, you can use a Map (or sometimes a Set) to make the comparison a lot more efficient.

```
Map<Id, ObjB__c> objAToObjBMap = new Map<Id, ObjB__c>();
for(ObjB__c rec2 :otherRecs){
    objAToObjBMap.put(rec2.ObjALookup__c, rec2);
}

for(ObjA__c rec1 :myRecs){
    if(objAToObjBMap.containsKey(rec1.Id){
        ObjB__c relatedRecord = objAToObjBMap.get(rec1.Id);
        // do work
    }
}
```

This approach means that you only loop N + M times.

If N and M are both 40 (a very modest number), the first approach would loop 1600 times, where the second approach would only loop 80 times. The difference only becomes more stark as N and M increase.

<sup>1: There are exceptions/workarounds to this. You can, for example, create a new instance of a record from trigger.new, like `Account newAcc = new Account(Id = trigger.new[0].Id);` and perform a DML update from an `after insert` trigger. I wouldn't recommend doing this if there is an alternative though.</sup>

Comment: Dear Derek,Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation and breaking down all the pros and cons with the above programming model. I have never programmed before, so this is turning out to be tremendous learning. I used the before insert/update and removed the update command altogether and atleast I am able to assign the required value. I will now move on to optimize the program as suggested by you and use map approach. Thanks again and will keep this thread posted.